# Can't create new controllers - Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This may seem like a duplicate question but the out is different and the fix  did not work for me.

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013. This is my first project using VS2013, I've been using VS2012 up until this point.

I am attempting to create a new controller in my ASP.NET MVC application. I am using Entity Framework 5 with code first (.NET 4.5). I want Visual Studio to create the template for me.

However, every time I try to create the controller I get the following error message:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Access to
>   the path
>   'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\SOMERANDOMGUID\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
>   is denied'

Is there some sort of bug in VS 2013? I can't figure out what this means, and restarting VS2013 does not help. Here are some things I have tried so far.

1. Start VS as Administrator
2. Gave "Everyone" read/write permission to the Local\Temp folder
3. Restarted Computer
4. Cleaned Project and deleted items out of bin folder
5. Uninstalled/reinstalled System.Web.MVC (I have also received this error for EntityFramework.dll as well)

Here are my models

```
namespace TestApp.Models
{
    public class Passenger
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ship
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ShipName{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<Passenger> Passenger { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I try to create a controller, everything is pretty straightforward.  I fill out my model and my context and click add.

And when I click Add I get the nasty access to the path is denied error

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus program.

Comment: Update entityframework to its latest version 6.0 and try.

Comment: Try once with adding everyone user with all permissions to avoid permission related issues. Also, recheck with application error event log viewer to encounter problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the Mircosoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll, I resolved using the following package-manager command:

update-package -reinstall Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

It basically does a uninstall/install of the package. NOTE: if you try to do a manual uninstall from the NuGet GUI it will not allow you for certain packages due to dependencies so I recommend using the console with command listed above.

For more info look here:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if that library is locked down by a running process.  If it is, you should be able to kill the process, delete the folder (since it is a temporary folder) and then start over.  Maybe the *.svchost.exe is holding it down.  That seems like a Windows file system default error response for locked files.